# Unity UnityEngine.VR.GetLocalRotation without VR enable

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

Is there a way to retrieve the head rotation without activating the VR ?

Thanks you very much

Comment: If you don't have VR enabled, you can't use VR methods.

Comment: Ok, then I am trying to find a way to directly call the methods or whatever that is calling the VR.
Or maybe a way to enable VR, but disable the camera

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally managed to something terrible.

I download the Cardboard API 0.5
Then, I use a CardboardMain prefab, and set the Distortion correction to None
I create after one update (yield return null) a new camera to replace to deactivated one from Cardboard API
I can retrieve the gyroscope modification by following the Head from the CardboardMain prefab

Good luck, tell me if you find better !

Ps : I am using this for this app http://lightgunmouse.com/